# Using would in sentences

Tags: will-would

I had eggs in the breakfast. But I wanted sausages.

Can I say, "I would have preferred a sausage"?

Comment: Note that you have eggs "for" breakfast, not "in the" breakfast.

Comment: Or eggs "at breakfast", but not "in the" breakfast.

Comment: Robusto, you are right. Aren't we missing "the",  "for the breakfast".

Comment: There is no missing "the" – the idiomatic way to say it is "for breakfast".

Answer (score 2):

Yes. That's exactly how I would say it.

Maybe just **sausage** rather than **a sausage,** but that depends on the type of sausage and how much you were having.

Comment: I'd say "probably," not "maybe." Spot on.